# Using MongoDBs aggregation, excluding sets from grouping and sum monthly revenues fails on $cond statement

Tags: mongodb, business-intelligence

my data:

db.customers:

```
{ "_id" : "email@address.de", "since" : ISODate("2010-12-08T09:26:33Z") }
```

db.orders

```
{ "_id" : "201234224", "order_date" : ISODate("2010-12-08T09:26:33Z"), "net_revenue" : "26.8400", "customer_id" : "email@address.de" }
{ "_id" : "201223245", "order_date" : ISODate("2011-04-16T16:09:17Z"), "net_revenue" : "26.8400", "customer_id" : "email@address.de" }
```

now i want to sum the `net_revenue` per month of returning customers, which means i have to exclude the inital order which equals with the `since` date. i came with the following statement

```
db.orders.aggregate( [
{
     $project:
       {
         _id:
           {
             $cond: { if: { $eq: [ db.customers.find({_id:"$customer_id"},{ _id:0,since:1 }), "$order_date" ] }, then: 0, else: 1 }
           }
       }
  },
{ $group : {
    _id: {
        year : { $year: "$order_date" },        
        month : { $month: "$order_date" }
    },
    count: { $sum: 1 },
    net_revenue: { $sum: 1 }
}}
]
```

);

i am not sure yet how to sum the `net_revenue`, but already my `$cond` fails with

```
errmsg" : "exception: the $cond operator requires an array of 3 operands",
```

do i need the else: ?

Comment: A note: at first glance your $net_revenue is a string, not a float. That will make it almost impossible to sum those values up in aggregation.

Comment: Have you checked to see if your parantheses and curly brackets are correct. I've checked the cond function and its seems to take 3 operands/arguments. There is a newer syntax though which can actually take an array using square brackets, just check the old way hasn't been deprecated.

Comment: You are trying to equate a cursor to a date. You can't execute a command inside an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: i found this `db.orders.find({net_revenue : {$exists : true}}).forEach( function(obj) { obj.net_revenue = new NumberInt( obj.net_revenue ); db.orders.save(obj); } );` to turn it into a Int, but NumberDouble is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as already commented: Your `net_revenue` is a string, and you can't create sums of strings. So first, we need to convert all of your `net_revenue` fields to a float, in order for being able to process them:

```
> var bulk = db.orders.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
> db.orders.find().forEach(function(order){
  order.net_revenue = parseFloat(order.net_revenue);   
  bulk.find({_id:order._id}).updateOne(order);
})
> bulk.execute()
```

You should make sure that `net_revenue` is saved as a float, not as a string.

Now, for the actual data you want. If you rephrase it, you want

> *The total of all `net_revenues` for all customers which have more than one order*

This translates to:

```
db.orders.aggregate(
  {$group: { _id:"$customer_id", orders:{$sum:1}, total_revenue:{$sum:"$net_revenue"} } },
  { $match: {orders:{ $gte:2 } } }
)
```

First, we group all orders by `$customer_id`, creating the new field order, which gets incremented by `1` for each document processed. Additionally, we create the new field `total_revenue` which gets incremented by the value of `net_revenue` of each document processed. Last but not least, we want only those customers which have placed more than one order. The output of the above aggregation is as expected:

```
{ "_id" : "email@address.de", "orders" : 2, "total_revenue" : 53.68 }
```

#### Edit

As per contraint, the first value can not be counted. Since we can not skip within groups in the aggregation framework, we need to use map reduce and kind of an ugly hack.

```
db.orders.mapReduce(
  // Map
  function(){

    // We need to have all values
    emit(this.customer_id,this.net_revenue);

  },

  // Reduce
  function(customer,values){
    var recurring_revenue = 0;

    // We build the sum for all key which have multiple values
    for(var idx = 1; idx < values.length; idx++) {
      recurring_revenue += values[idx];
    }

    // here is the hack:
    // Since the reduce phase is only run if a key has multiple values
    // We need to make sure that the recurring revenues are can be queried in our
    // output collection
    var reduced = {
       "recurring":recurring_revenue,
       "orders":values.length
    };

    return reduced
  },
  // Options for map/reduce
  {
      // Since we want to skip the first order by date
      // we need to make sure the original documents are fed into the map
      // function in order of date
      sort:{"order_date":1},
      out:"recurring_revenues"
   })
```

Now, in order to get all customers which have a recurring revenue, we need to query our `out` collection

```
db.recurring_revenues.find({"value.orders":{$gt:1}})
```

which should return

```
{ "_id" : "email@address.de", "value" : { "recurring" : 26.84, "orders" : 2 } }
```

as per example data given. If there is more than one customer with more than one order, they will be returned, of course.

#### Edit 2

In 2.4 , you do not have the bulk operations. The conversion can be done using

```
db.order.find().forEach(function(order) {
  var rev =  parseFloat(order.net_revenue);
  db.order.update({_id:order._id},{$set:{"net_revenue":rev}});
}
```

which will be considerably slower in big collections.

Comment: thanks for your help. i found this for converting the string `db.orders.find({net_revenue : {$exists : true}}).forEach( function(obj) { obj.net_revenue = new NumberInt( obj.net_revenue ); db.orders.save(obj); } );`just with what i have to replace NumberInt? NumberDouble/NumberFloat doesn't work. Furthermore, i'd like to sum only over the returning orders, meaning excluding the first order

Comment: kritop: The code for converting as shown above works. Tested. Use it. Second: Even the first order of a returning customer counts to his revenue, doesn't it?

Comment: to his yes, but not to the returning customers revenue.

Comment: `var bulk = db.orders.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()`returns
`Wed Nov 19 10:36:17.474 TypeError: Property 'initializeUnorderedBulkOp' of object churn.orders is not a function`

Comment: Ok, then it get _a lot more_ complicated, since you simply can not skip in groups. You have to use map/reduce then. I'll work it out and edit accordingly

Comment: kritop: What the heck is `churn`? And what version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: its a collection, and its `MongoDB shell version: 2.4.12`

Comment: thanks!, i now have the customers with total recurring order amounts and values. how would i add grouping by month/year? or how could i now perform an aggregate/grouping on that result list to see the avg amount of orders

Comment: i accepted your answer and created a follow up questions, as i figured its as complex as the one before :) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021561/group-mongodb-collection-by-month-and-aggregate-revenue