# group MongoDB collection by month and aggregate revenue for churn/revenue chart

Tags: mongodb, business-intelligence

db.orders (only small excerpt)

```
{ "_id" : "20101200221", "order_date" : ISODate("2010-12-12T13:11:15Z"), "net_revenue" : 19.36, "customer_id" : "aaa@gmx.net" }
{ "_id" : "20111003701", "order_date" : ISODate("2011-10-12T08:40:55Z"), "net_revenue" : 15.13, "customer_id" : "aaa@gmx.net" }
{ "_id" : "20111204977", "order_date" : ISODate("2011-12-07T09:13:47Z"), "net_revenue" : 15.13, "customer_id" : "aaa@gmx.net" }
{ "_id" : "20120206778", "order_date" : ISODate("2012-02-04T09:46:35Z"), "net_revenue" : 15.13, "customer_id" : "aaa@gmx.net" }
{ "_id" : "20120408856", "order_date" : ISODate("2012-04-15T10:37:55Z"), "net_revenue" : 12.65, "customer_id" : "aaa@gmx.net" }
{ "_id" : "20101200001", "order_date" : ISODate("2010-12-07T17:40:54Z"), "net_revenue" : 26.34, "customer_id" : "bbb@web.de" }
{ "_id" : "20100100473", "order_date" : ISODate("2011-01-31T06:38:03Z"), "net_revenue" : 34.34, "customer_id" : "bbb@web.de" }
{ "_id" : "20110601857", "order_date" : ISODate("2011-06-14T08:40:39Z"), "net_revenue" : 16.13, "customer_id" : "bbb@web.de" }
{ "_id" : "20111003719", "order_date" : ISODate("2011-10-13T06:43:50Z"), "net_revenue" : 60.75, "customer_id" : "bbb@web.de" }
{ "_id" : "20120912597", "order_date" : ISODate("2012-09-20T09:16:08Z"), "net_revenue" : 38.6, "customer_id" : "bbb@web.de" }
{ "_id" : "20130101745", "order_date" : ISODate("2013-01-28T11:40:17Z"), "net_revenue" : 20.14, "customer_id" : "bbb@web.de" }
{ "_id" : "20140615910", "order_date" : ISODate("2014-06-10T14:55:11Z"), "net_revenue" : 32.45, "customer_id" : "bbb@web.de" }`
```

to create a churn/revenue graph i need to group orders by month of their initial/first order per customer. in the excerpt you can see both initial orders were done 12/2010 so all the following orders should fall into this group, lets call it 1, group 2 would be everyone who had his initial order 01/2011 etc.
every group will be its own graph and will be stacked like this:
[image]

the orders in the groups also have to be grouped again into months and the revenue has to be summed.
i hope i could make it clear what i am trying to achieve! it's all day i am trying to figure out a way how to produce the data for the graph. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want the revenue by customer and by month.

The $group operator in an aggregate query is exactly what you're looking for here.

```js
db.orders.aggregate([
    { $group : { 
            _id: { 
                customer_id: "$customer_id",
                month: {$month: "$order_date"}
            },
            revenue: {$sum: "$net_revenue"} 
        }
    }], ... );
```

With the above query, a customer will appear more than once if they order on separate months. I didn't understand if that is what you wanted or not. If instead you're wanting the total value for ALL orders from that customer, but sorted also by the FIRST time they ever ordered, do this instead:

```js
db.orders.aggregate([
    { $sort: { order_date : 1 } }, //order by date so that $first is correct
    { $group : { 
            _id: { 
                customer_id: "$customer_id",                
            },
            month: { $first: {$month: "$order_date"} }
            revenue: {$sum: "$net_revenue"} 
        }
    }], ... );
```

Comment: basically its a different graph/dataset for every month since lauch. you take everyone who first ordered in month 1 (12/2010) and collect all their orders, then you sort them by month and sum the revenues. then you can see if today, there are still some of your month 1 customer adding any revenue to your monthly. the same you do for month 2,3 etc. if you stack all of them you have the above graph.

Comment: If the two queries aren't what you're looking for, I recommend giving an example output in your question. As in, "I'm trying to make this data look like this:" with enough sample data to clearly convey the grouping you're looking for, as I still don't understand how what you're asking for is different than what I've provided.

Comment: i was hoping the graph makes it pretty visible what is needed, its hard to write down the exact data. for the graph for example you need 18 different sets, because its 18 different graphs stacked. 1 would be all orders of customers who had their first oder in the first month + all their recurring orders, their revenue grouped by month. then 2 would be everyone who had their order in the second month + all their recurring orders, their revenue grouped by month...etc in the excerpt we only have data for one graph which stars on month 1 but would even have a revenue of  32.45 in june/2014

Comment: Perhaps someone else will understand what you're looking for better than me.